# Availability report kibana

Tags: logging, report, kibana

i have few weeks with elasticsearch and kibana4, i want to implement a availability report based in logs.

here is what i have

Reporting period:
from March 10 2015, 23:59:59.000
to March 1rd 2015, 00:00:00.000

Some logs

```
Alarm(1) AlarmTitle     DEVICE HAS STOPPED RESPONDING TO POLLS 
    ProbableCauseID     10009
    StartTime       March 3rd 2015, 13:04:07.000
    EndTime     March 3rd 2015, 13:08:59.000


Alarm(2) AlarmTitle     DEVICE IN MAINTENANCE MODE 
    ProbableCauseID     10222
    EndTime     March 3rd 2015, 12:49:10.000
    StartTime   March 3rd 2015, 12:46:39.000
```

The Availability must be 100% of the Reporting period less the sum of time of the duration of Alarm(1).
The sum of time of Alarm(2) count as availability.

```
It's posible with kibana do this ? and have a Top N of Availability ?
```

Thanks a LOT !!!

Comment: If you're using logstash, compute the duration of each event as it is processed.  You'll have to do this with the ruby{} filter, like this (if they're strings):

    event['duration'] = ((DateTime.parse(event['endDate']) - DateTime.parse(event['startDate'])) * 86400).to_i

Then, in Kibana, you can sum the 'duration' field.

I don't know how to get Kibana to graph (100-sum), so I've only left you this comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks, i found the "script fields" option, now im reading about it, and it can be done using that tool.